# Passportjs using email field not username

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

**edit #1**

Here is what I have tried so far, also in the register and login forms I have `name="email"` on both.

user routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.render('register.hbs', {
    pageTitle: 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login.hbs', {
    pageTitle: 'Login'
  });
});

router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  var schoolName = req.body.schoolName;
  var schoolAddress = req.body.schoolAddress;
  var city = req.body.city;
  var zipCode = req.body.zipCode;
  var postalAddress = req.body.postalAddress;
  var postalCity = req.body.postalCity;
  var postalZipCode = req.body.postalZipCode;
  var telephone = req.body.telephone;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var schoolType = req.body.schoolType;
  var schoolDistrict = req.body.schoolDistrict;
  var schoolRegion = req.body.schoolRegion;
  var curriculum = req.body.curriculum;
  var directorName = req.body.directorName;
  var directorTelephone = req.body.directorTelephone;
  var directorEmail = req.body.directorEmail;
  var schoolLiaisonName = req.body.schoolLiaisonName;
  var schoolLiaisonTelephone = req.body.schoolLiaisonTelephone;
  var schoolLiaisonEmail = req.body.schoolLiaisonEmail;
  var schoolLiaisonPosition = req.body.schoolLiaisonPosition;
  var schoolLiaisonTShirt = req.body.schoolLiaisonTShirt;
  var schoolLiaisonTutorMentor = req.body.schoolLiaisonTutorMentor;

  // validations
  req.checkBody('schoolName', 'The school name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolAddress', 'The school address is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('city', 'The city is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('zipCode', 'This zip code is required').notEmpty();
  // req.checkBody('postalAddress', 'The postal address is required').notEmpty();
  // req.checkBody('postalCity', 'The postal city is required').notEmpty();
  // req.checkBody('postalZipCode', 'The postal zip code is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('telephone', 'A telephone number is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'An account email is required').notEmpty();
  // req.checkBody('email', 'This account email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'An account password is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolType', 'A school type is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolDistrict', 'A school district is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolRegion', 'A school region is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('curriculum', 'A curriculum is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('directorName', 'A directors name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('directorTelephone', 'A directors telephone is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('directorEmail', 'A directors email is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('directorEmail', 'This email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('schoolLiaisonName', 'A school liaison name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolLiaisonTelephone', 'A school liaison telephone is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolLiaisonEmail', 'The school liaison email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('schoolLiaisonEmail', 'A school liaison email is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolLiaisonPosition', 'A school liaison position is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolLiaisonTShirt', 'A school liaison t-shirt size is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('schoolLiaisonTutorMentor', 'A school liaison tutor/mentor is required').notEmpty();

  var errors = req.validationErrors();

  if (errors) {
    res.render('register', {
      errors:errors
    });
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      schoolName: schoolName,
      schoolAddress: schoolAddress,
      city: city,
      zipCode: zipCode,
      postalAddress: postalAddress,
      postalCity: postalCity,
      postalZipCode: postalZipCode,
      telephone: telephone,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      schoolType: schoolType,
      schoolDistrict: schoolDistrict,
      schoolRegion: schoolRegion,
      curriculum: curriculum,
      directorName: directorName,
      directorTelephone: directorTelephone,
      directorEmail: directorEmail,
      schoolLiaisonName: schoolLiaisonName,
      schoolLiaisonTelephone: schoolLiaisonTelephone,
      schoolLiaisonEmail: schoolLiaisonEmail,
      schoolLiaisonPosition: schoolLiaisonPosition,
      schoolLiaisonTShirt: schoolLiaisonTShirt,
      schoolLiaisonTutorMentor: schoolLiaisonTutorMentor,
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });

    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered, you can now login!');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  },
  function(email, password, done) {
    User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown Email Address'});
      }

      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, ismatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(ismatch){
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/users/login',
  successFlash: 'Welcome!',
  failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password.'
}), function(req, res) {
  // res.redirect('/' + req.user.username);
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now logged out!')
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

user model

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var app = express();

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pol-development');
}

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connection has been established");
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  schoolName: String,
  schoolAddress: String,
  schoolAddress2: String,
  city: String,
  zipCode: String,
  addressCheck: Boolean,
  postalAddress: String,
  postalCity: String,
  postalZipCode: String,
  telephone: Number,
  fax: Number,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  schoolType: String,
  schoolDistrict: String,
  schoolRegion: String,
  curriculum: String,
  participationBefore: Boolean,
  participationYears: Number,
  directorName: String,
  directorTelephone: Number,
  directorEmail: String,
  directorAttendanceRehersal: Boolean,
  directorAttendanceEvent: Boolean,
  schoolLiaisonName: String,
  schoolLiaisonTelephone: Number,
  schoolLiaisonEmail: String,
  schoolLiaisonPosition: String,
  schoolLiaisonOtherPosition: String,
  schoolLiaisonTShirt: String,
  schoolLiaisonTutorMentor: String,
  attendanceRehersal: Boolean,
  attendanceEvent: Boolean
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
}

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
  var query = {email: email};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  user.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, ismatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, ismatch);
  });
}
```

I'm using passportjs but I don't have a username field but an email field, therefore I would like to be able to target the email field.

How would I go about doing this, I have already tried a few things to get this running, but no joy.

Thank you!

Comment: `I have already tried a few things` Can we see some of them in an [edit]?

Comment: @LW001Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Passport [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/) states the following

> The local authentication strategy authenticates users using a username
>   and password.

You can use an email as the username but said email must be the value of a key that is explicitly labeled `username` when you send the request.

Example:

```
{
    "username": "anna@test.com",
    "password": "12345678"
}
```